# Do I need to use ready events for Dom manipulation?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I wonder - do I need to use ready events like `$(document).ready()` in jQuery for DOM manipulation. For example, I have a javascript function:

```
function handler(input,id) {        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById(input).value = id;
        document.search_form.submit();  
    });

}
```

Comment: Only if `handler` executes before the DOM finishes loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments regarding your code :

```
1. function handler(input,id) {        
2.    $(document).ready(function(){
3.        document.getElementById(input).value = id;
4.        document.search_form.submit();  
5.    });
6.}
```

Line 2 and 5 are not needed - since this is a function and will be called rather than execute on load you don't need the ready handler. The `$(document).ready(function() {` line means execute the following code when the `DOM` is `ready` - if its inside a function like yours is its not needed (but will still work). You can read more about `ready()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Line 3 can be changed to `$('#'+input).val(id);` this uses the jQuery [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to change the value.

Ending up with

```
function handler(input,id) {        
  $('#'+input).val(id);
  document.search_form.submit();  
}
```

You could probably change your code a little more judging by the function name ....

Answer (score 6):

No. God no. Don't do that. `$(document).ready()` should never be inside a function.

Comment: It wouldn't, but it's pointless processing, and even more pointless encapsulation.

Comment: document ready may well be long past by the time the handler is called

Comment: Instead, call the function from a place where you are sure the DOM has loaded (that can be inside a `$(document).ready()`). @Blazemonger If you do that after the DOM has loaded, will it still work?

Comment: @11684 It won't actually cause problems. [See for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Dus9v/)

Comment: Why not? It doesn't especially add any overhead, since the code will be immediately added. (2 more functions called -- not so many.)

Comment: Sure, if your handler isn't being called often. But in any case, this kind of practice shouldn't be encouraged. It adds unneeded complexity to the code, both from a call-stack point of view, and from a human-readable point of view.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not necessary. You can instead put the JavaScript at the very end of your document before the `</body>` tag.

You can also use the `window.onload` event, although I wouldn't recommend it, since this won't fire until after all images have loaded, which can be a long time after the DOM is loaded.

One of these three approaches is the best idea, though, since you can't use JavaScript to manipulate DOM elements until those elements have completely loaded in the browser.

That said, there's probably no good reason to put `$(document).ready` inside another function. In almost all cases, you want `$(document).ready` to surround your other JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. It depends on when you are about to manipulate the DOM. This means you should consider where your javascript should be placed, before, after or inside the `<body>`.